# How to avoid change in the data format while load a tsv file using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a .tsv file and I am loading it using pandas. Some of `id` column values have a format like `6.0642E+12`. I would like to convert these values as a string. What would be a better way of doing it?
I have used the following code to load the file.

```
pd.read_csv(collating_data, sep="\t", header=0)
```

The affected column looks like this

```
    item_id
0   DB009600110C25
1   6.0642E+12
2   1.10517E+12
3   1.10517E+12
4   2.2007E+12
```

I would appreciate your feedback. Thanks

Comment: Can you post a sample of the file that you're reading i.e. the first 4 rows. If you want to change the data type of a series from an object to a string you can do use `Series.astype(str)`

Comment: What is the desired value of row 1 index supposed to be? Are you alright with a value of '606420000000'?

Comment: Just a warning, if you have "ids" that are in scientific notion, you likely have a problem as you have the potential for huge loss of information.

Comment: You can set the data type of a column using the `dtype` parameter to `pandas.read_csv()`